# How to recall function in .py file from notebook of Jupyter

Tags: python, jupyter

I have a .py file defining some functions(or methods). How to recall those functions from notebook of Jupyter.

Comment: Do you mean "_call_ those functions"? You may want to treat the file as a module (read about writing modules here http://www.learnpython.org/en/Modules_and_Packages or elsewhere).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it may be like that:

```
 from name_file.py import name_function
```

(now I can use **name_fuction** function)

or for all functions:

```
import name_file.py
```

(now I can use **name_file.name_fuction** function)